# Static views across different Activities

Tags: android, animation, view, fragment

I have two different activities that have the same views in the header.
Is there a way to transition between these two activities without causing a screen flicker so the same views appear to be static?

The current implementation of the app has only one Activity with a bunch of fragments. It's kinda hard to follow everything, so creating different Activities will really help follow the flow.

Any recommendations?

Comment: yay. That's what we are currently using. It just seems really really easy to create an application that is only 1 activity with a whole bunch of fragments. I wanted to see if that was avoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to transition between these two activities without causing a screen flicker so the same views appear to be static?

No, sorry.

> The current implementation of the app has only one Activity with a bunch of fragments. It's kinda hard to follow everything, so creating different Activities will really help follow the flow.

Then relax your "without causing a screen flicker so the same views appear to be static" requirement.

To put this in Web terms, you are saying "gee, having all this stuff in one Web page is really complicated, but I need it to be in one Web page because we do not want the page header to 'flicker' when the user clicks a link to load the next Web page". Activities are roughly analogous to Web pages -- there will be a visible transition between them, and they take up the full rendering space. You can get the visual effect you want with fragments -- just as you can on the Web using DOM rewriting and such -- at the cost of complexity.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Sometimes its hard to convince people that apps just can't look the same on Android and iOS, lol.